# Error: Command already exists in a cog - Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making an economy bot and I've added a bunch of commands inside a cog. When the commands were outside the cog there wasn't an error, however when I put them inside the cog no matter what I name the command the IDE says it already exists. I was able to bypass this by typing:

```py
bot.remove_command("withdraw")
bot.remove_command("deposit")
bot.remove_command("send")
bot.remove_command("rob")
bot.remove_command("slots")
bot.remove_command("balance")
bot.remove_command("beg")
bot.remove_command("shop")
bot.remove_command("buy")
bot.remove_command("inventory")
bot.add_cog(Metacash(bot))
```

At the end of the class per every single command I've made and it somehow works. Is this necessary or is there a different way to do this?

Edit: Here is a broader example of my code.

```py
# Beginning of economy system.
class Metacash(commands.Cog):
    @bot.command()
    async def shop(self, ctx):
        # Shop stuff
    
    @bot.command()
    async def buy(self, ctx, item, amount):
        # Buy stuff

    @bot.command()
    async def inventory(self, ctx):
        # Inventory stuff

    @bot.command(help="Withdraw money from your bank to your wallet.")
    async def withdraw(self, ctx, amount=None):
        # Withdraw stuff

    @bot.command(help="Deposit money from your wallet to your bank.")
    async def deposit(self, ctx, amount=None):
        # Deposit stuff

    @bot.command(help="Send money to someone.")
    async def send(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, amount=None):
        # Send stuff

    @bot.command(help="Steal a random amount of MetaCash from someone.")
    async def rob(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        # Rob stuff

    @bot.command(help="Slots gambling game.")
    async def slots(self, ctx, amount=None):
        # Slots stuff

    @bot.command(help="Displays current wallet and bank balance.")
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        # Balance stuff

    @bot.command(help="Gives you MetaCash.")
    async def beg(self, ctx):
        # Beg stuff

bot.remove_command("withdraw")
bot.remove_command("deposit")
bot.remove_command("send")
bot.remove_command("rob")
bot.remove_command("slots")
bot.remove_command("balance")
bot.remove_command("beg")
bot.remove_command("shop")
bot.remove_command("buy")
bot.remove_command("inventory")
bot.add_cog(Metacash(bot))
# End of economy system.
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the context of the code. Could you add more code with comments showing what specifically you are seeing?

Comment: It's a ton of code, but I can summarize it a bit...